# Error: Could not find or load main class com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

Any idea why Cygnus reports this error (cygnus log)? Removed image, downloaded new, yet cygnus reports dame error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling this image `fiware/cygnus-ngsi:1.9.0` fixes the problem.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there were a problem with the docker build, introduced after 1.9.0 releasing.

It should be fixed now. You can use `fiware/cygnus-ngsi:latest` if you want.